# Looping over three days

Tags: python, postgresql

In my table in the postgres I have the users and the time they've made a picture. I would like to define different tracks of the users. To start with I say that within 3 days for the same user is the same track, and then starts the next one. I would like to add a column to my table, where I will save the unique number of the track. I have figured out the how to define the start and end day of every user. But I am not sure how to divide that now to every three days.

```
    cur.execute("""SELECT users From table;""")
    dbrows = cur.fetchall()
    for k in set(dbrows):
        cur.execute("""SELECT time From table where users ="""+k+""";""")
        dbrows_time = cur.fetchall()
        time_period = []
        for i in dbrows_time:
            new_date_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            new_date = new_date_time[0:10]
            time_period.append(new_date)
        period = len(set(time_period))
        beginning = time_period[0]
        end = time_period[-1]
        beginning = datetime.strptime(beginning, "%Y-%m-%d")
        end = datetime.strptime(end, "%Y-%m-%d")
        delta=timedelta(days=3)
```

Here should come some loop "for every three days create a new unique number". Or may be it should be done in SQL when I insert in the table?

```
        INSERT INTO table_tracks the number of each track
        conn.commit()
```

I can insert some number every three entries like this, but I am not sure how to do the three days thing.

```
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO table_track (id, users, link, tags, time, track, geom) select id, users, link, tags, time, ((row_number() over (ORDER BY users DESC) - 1) / 3) + 1, geom from table;""")
```

The data is basically in the form:

```
    user time      geometry
    1    1.03.2015 geometry
    1    2.03.2015 geometry
    ......
    2    01.03.2015 geometry
    ......
```

Every user has a unique id and the time I convert to the datetime format. Desired results are:

```
    user time geometry       track_number 
    1    1.03.2015 geometry  1
    1    2.03.2015 geometry  1
    ......
    2    01.03.2015 geometry 15
    ......
```

The track_number is unique per user and per three days. Let's say the user makes a picture on 1st, 2nd and 3rd of March and then on 4th, 5th and 6th. These would be to different tracks (which is may be not ideal in the real word). But it is especially interesting if the pictures are on 1st, 2nd of March and 4th, 5th, 8th. Then I would say these should be three tracks: 1st and 2nd, 4th and 5th and 8th. So I mean a timedelta by three days. If there is only one picture within three days then it is only one track. Something like that. Thank you!!
Any ideas or directions are highly appreciated!

Comment: You can do this all in SQL, but without sample data and desired results, there is not much guidance on showing methods to do it.

Comment: The data is basically in the form: columns: user time geometry. Every user has a unique id and the time I convert to the datetime format. Desired results are: columns: user time geometry track_number. Where the track_number is unique per user and per three days. Let's say the user makes a picture on 1st, 2nd and 3rd of March and then on 4th, 5th and 6th.

Comment: These would be to different tracks (which is may be not ideal in the real word). But it is especially interesting if the pictures are on 1st, 2nd of March and 4th, 5th, 8th. Then I would say these should be three tracks: 1st and 2nd, 4th and 5th and 8th. So I mean a timedelta by three days. If there is only one picture within three days then it is only one track. Something like that. Thank you!!

Comment: Move all the information from comments to the question